# My images aren't showing up in listcontrol

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm

I'm not sure whats wrong here, but my images don't show up. All of the other properties of my object show up, but the image never loads. I have tried the url in the browser and the image shows up there. Here is my code:

Using MVVM Light, setting the view model

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

My xaml with data binding

```
               <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Height="200">
                                <!--<StackPanel.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="PodImages\podstate-Clip.png" />
                                </StackPanel.Background>-->
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summ}" FontSize="32" Foreground="Green"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}" FontSize="32" Foreground="Blue"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding L1}" Width="350" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Blue"/>                                        
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Val}"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

My data model

```
public class Offer
{

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Summ { get; set; }
    public string L1 { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }
}
```

My data service callback. This is setting my collection as expected. ImageUri contains a valid uri.

```
private void OffersLoaded(OfferDetailsWithMsg offers)
    {
        AllItems = offers.Items.Where(item => item.Type == 0).ToList();
    }
```

finally my AllItems property. Yes I am calling `RaisePropertyChanged` (supporting properties removed for brevity)

```
public List<Offers> AllItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _allItems;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_allItems == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _allItems= value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(AllItemsPropertyName);

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the source of the page?

Comment: It's a windows phone app and I cannot view the resulting source unless someone knows a way to do that

Comment: I hard coded a url to a random image online and that worked out. Not sure why it won't display images from my cdn.

Comment: Have you checked the headers coming back from your CDN? Perhaps it isn't setting the MIME type, or some such, and the `Image` control can't figure out that it's an image?

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I'll check on that.

Comment: Did binding the Uri to the Image rather than the string work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah, these are Gif's and it appears Gif's aren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to bind to a `Uri` rather than a `string`. In the Offer class, try adding the following property, and bind to that.

```
public Uri ImgUri
{
     get
     {   
          return new Uri(ImageUri, UriKind.Absolute); //or relative, if it is relative
     }
}
```